# Abp Auto Api Controllers not binding my Custom attribute

Tags: abp

I created a custom Attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class OrganizationPlayerOnlyAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter, IFilterFactory, IScopedDependency
{
    public ICurrentUser _currentUser;
    public IMemberAppService _memberAppService;

public bool IsReusable => false;

public IFilterMetadata CreateInstance(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    _currentUser = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICurrentUser>();
    _memberAppService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMemberAppService>();

    return ActivatorUtilities
       .GetServiceOrCreateInstance<OrganizationPlayerOnlyAttribute>(serviceProvider);
}


public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

And then added it to an AppService and a Controller

```
public class SomeController : AbpController
{
    public SomeController (){ }

    [HttpGet("disambiguator")]
    [OrganizationPlayerOnly]
    public Task<int> GetDisambiguatorAsync(string userName)
    {
        return _disambiguatorAppService.GetDisambiguatorAsync(userName);
    }
```

}

```
public class MyAccountAppService : AccountAppService, IDisambiguatorAppService
{
    [OrganizationPlayerOnly]
    public Task Test()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The controller is working fine but the AppService is not. My guess is I am missing a step when configuring the auto controllers method

```
    Configure<AbpAspNetCoreMvcOptions>(options => {
     options.ConventionalControllers.Create(typeof(MainStageApplicationModule).Assembly);
    }});
```

Comment: Hi, could you please review the [document](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/7.1/API/Auto-API-Controllers)?

Comment: Hi, it works when I try it on version 7.0.2, can you give me the version information?

Comment: Hi i'ts ABP 5.3.4